# Set heading in the margin to the left of text

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, marginpar

I would like to style the `\paragraph` heading so that it is set in the margin to the left of the text. I experimented with the `titlesec` package, and I get the heading wrapped to the left of the text, but not in the margin.

So, given the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,]{article}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[wrap]{\bfseries}{}{}{}[]
\begin{document}

\section{A Section}

Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.

\paragraph{Heading in the margin}

More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text.
More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text.

\end{document}
```

the output looks like

```
           1 A Section

           Some text Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some 
           text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.

           Heading    More text. More text. More text. More text. More 
           in Margin  text. More text. More text. More text. More text.
                      More text. More text.
```

But I want to achieve

```
           1 A Section

           Some text Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some 
           text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.

  Heading  More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More 
in Margin  text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text.
           More text.
```

Any way to tweak `\titleformat` for this? Or use another mechanism?

---

***Note:*** I know that I can use the `\marginpar` command to print directly in the margin, but I want to keep the `\paragraph` heading for this, because the document part get auto generated by a markdown converter.

***Note 2:*** Here a picture which I refer to in a comment (keeping a reference here, because I don't know whether unreferenced images get deleted):

[image]

***Note 3:*** Here the snippet from the `pandoc` template I refer to in my comment below:

```
% Redefines (sub)paragraphs to behave more like sections
\ifx\paragraph\undefined\else
\let\oldparagraph\paragraph
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
\ifx\subparagraph\undefined\else
\let\oldsubparagraph\subparagraph
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\oldsubparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are five examples of what can be done withe `leftmargin` shape:

```
\documentclass[12pt,]{article}
\usepackage[showframe, marginparwidth=60pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell, booktabs, eqparbox}
 \usepackage[compact, explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[leftmargin]{\bfseries\color{IndianRed}}{}{}{\color{IndianRed}\llap{\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\raggedleft#1}}}[\hskip-\parindent]

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{A Section}

Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.

\paragraph{Heading in the margin}

\lipsum[11]

\titleformat{\paragraph}[leftmargin]{\bfseries\arrayrulecolor{IndianRed}}{}{}%
{\llap{\raisebox{\baselineskip}{\begin{tabularx}{\marginparwidth}[t]{@{}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X@{}}\toprule#1\\\bottomrule\end{tabularx}}}}[\hskip-\parindent]

\paragraph{Another heading}
\lipsum[11]

\titleformat{\paragraph}[leftmargin]{\bfseries}{}{}%
{\llap{\begin{tabularx}{\marginparwidth}[t]{@{}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X!{\color{IndianRed}\vrule width2.5pt}}#1 \end{tabularx}}}[\hskip-\parindent]

\paragraph{Another heading}

\lipsum[11]

\titleformat{\paragraph}[leftmargin]{\bfseries\setlength\fboxrule{1pt}}{}{}%
{\llap{\fcolorbox{IndianRed}{white}{\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\raggedleft#1\\\mdseries(fixed width)}}}}[\hskip-\parindent]

\paragraph{Another heading}

\lipsum[11]

\titleformat{\paragraph}[leftmargin]{\bfseries\setlength\fboxrule{1pt}}{}{}%
{\llap{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height + \baselineskip-0.5 \fboxrule\relax}{\fcolorbox{IndianRed}{white}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{}}\makecell{#1}\end{tabular}}}}}[\hskip-\parindent]

\paragraph{Another\\heading\\\mdseries(variable\\\mdseries width)}

\lipsum[11]

\paragraph{Short\\head}

\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does work in your MWE. :-) Thanks. Doesn't work yet in my real world doc. :-( I get a vertical space at the beginning of the main text paragraph. See http://i.stack.imgur.com/CUrgb.png. Have to play with it to find out what's the culprit.

Comment: Could you  post a minimal compilable example showing the problem?

Comment: Actually not yet - My real world document uses a `pandoc` template which draws in lots of packages, so I have to play with it a bit before I (hopefully) find what's the culprit... My newest suspicion is that it may be due to rubber lengths in the page layout. (The inter-paragraph spacing gets stretched but the margin doesn't go with it.) - Will check, when I'm back at my TeX-machine.

Comment: @halloleo: If there is normal text after the heading and before the environment, it shouldn't happen. If the description comes  just after the heading, that's normal (and there's a workaround). The best would be to post an example-code.

Comment: I found the culprit: The `pandoc` template adds some redefinitions of the `\(sub)paragraph` commands which throws `titlesec` off. (See code snippet in *Note 3* at the bottom of my question.) - Removing them rectifies the issue. :-)