# Paragraph heading in both sides margin with titlesec

Tags: margins, titlesec, geometry

When using [Set heading in the margin to the left of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320763/set-heading-in-the-margin-to-the-left-of-text) this method to place paragraph headings in the margin, this works for single-column documents. But when the `twocolumn` option of `geometry` is used (in `report` class), the second column's heading overlaps into the first column's text. Is there a way to have the left column's headings in the left margin, and right column's headings in the right margin?

Comment: Which code are you referring to in your linked question, the answer or the question? Please include code in your questions, we will not go on a mission, you should make it as easy for us as possible to help you please